# How to download .PHP file from the server with php or javascript/jquery script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This is my [link](http://track2.unitrackadmin.co.in/application/models/User_model.php) and i want to download this code page(original back end code) as plain text format

is it possible with php/javascript/jquery code?

Comment: You can write PHP code that opens the file and serves the content as `text/plain`. Just use `header()`, `file_get_contents()` and `echo`. Not possible with client side code, otherwise anybody could grab PHP source code from any PHP website, which would be a massive security hole.

Comment: another possibility would be to rename the file first with another extention (.$$$) and link to that file. (tbh this once happend to me with auto-saved backup files of an editor....major sec hole there...oops. 20 years ago)

Comment: One way is to browse to your file manager and look for a download button there. Else, you cannot simply download a .php file from a server since it is executed on the server. That means you need to have exclusive rights over the webhost to download a .php file. Hope you understand. (Deepak Chahar, quite a famous name in IPL bdw  . *pun intended*)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.

It is back-end code that is always parsed when it is run. You'd need to use FTP, SSH or something to remote into the server and download the code itself.

It'd be possible to have another file that would output the contents of the code, but it'd be a pretty major security issue if the raw code files could be downloaded.

Comment: and what php/javascript/jquery script code add to the backend php/js file that download php file as plain text onload/on page load